# Limit of a sequence involving some exponentials

Tags: limits

According to WolframAlpha, it holds that
$$\lim_{x\to0+} \frac{\exp(\alpha x) - \exp(x^2)^{1/2}}{[\exp(x^2)-1]^{1/2} \exp(x^2)^{1/2}} = \alpha$$
for any $\alpha\in\mathbf{R}$.
Please note that it is a limit **from the right**. (A limit from the left would give $-\alpha$.)

I do not see how to compute this limit by hand.
L'Hôpital's rule does not get me far, at least if I am correct.

I would appreciate any hints for the computation of this limit.

Comment: I don't understand. Is the $1/2$ exponent on $x^2$ or on $\exp$? In the first case, since $x>0$, why are you writing $(x^2)^{1/2}$ instead of $x$? If it's the second case, parentheses need to be used properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\exp(x) - 1}{x} = 1.$$

With this in mind, we compute
\begin{align}
  \frac{\exp(\alpha x) - \exp(x^2)^{1/2}}{(\exp(x^2)-1)^{1/2} \exp(x^2)^{1/2}} &= \frac{ \frac{\exp(\alpha x) - 1}{\alpha x} \cdot \alpha x - \frac{\exp(x^{2}/2)-1}{x^{2}/2} \cdot x^2/2} {\left(\frac{\exp(x^2) - 1}{x^2}\right)^{1/2} \cdot x \cdot \exp(x^2/2)}
\end{align}
for each $x\in\mathbf{R}$.

Cancelling $x$ from both numerator and denominator, we get

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{ \frac{\exp(\alpha x) - 1}{\alpha x} \cdot \alpha - \frac{\exp(x^{2}/2)-1}{x^{2}/2} \cdot x/2} {\left(\frac{\exp(x^2) - 1}{x^2}\right)^{1/2} \cdot \exp(x^2/2)} = \frac{1\cdot\alpha - 1\cdot0}{1\cdot1} = \alpha$$
as required.